# Select que não retorne em branco SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select 'TEM' AS InSituacao
    from GTCLogist
where NrPlacaCarreta = ''
and ID <> '35514'
and year(DtBase)=year(GETDATE())
and MONTH(DtBase)=MONTH(GETDATE())
and DAY(DtBase)=DAY(GETDATE())
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Possuo o SQL acima, preciso que quando o campo estiver em branco não me retorne nada. Já tentei o `isnull` mas como o campo ta em branco e não `null` não sei se fiz o uso correto.

Comment: Qual campo que quando estiver em branco não deve te retornar nada?

Comment: `NrPlacaCarreta`

Comment: Tentou usar `coalesce`?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "estiver em branco não retorne nada"?

Comment: Qual a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: @Kevin.F: existe diferença entre coluna sem valor (NULL), coluna com string vazio (''), ou coluna em branco ('    ').  O que significa "em branco", no seu caso?

Comment: @Kevin.F: Como está declarada a coluna DtBase? Se ela está como datetime, a coluna contém somente data (por exemplo, "2015-02-22") ou contém data e hora (por exemplo, "2015-02-22 02:35:12") ?

Comment: Tente: `nomeColuna IS NOT NULL AND nomeColuna != ''`, assim se a coluna estiver com valor `null` ou se estiver com o valor branco (como acho que é o seu caso) não irá trazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"(...) preciso que quando o campo estiver em branco não me retorne nada"*

Kevin, avalie a seguinte sugestão:

```
-- código #1 v2
declare @Hoje date;

set @Hoje= cast(current_timestamp as date);

SELECT ID, NrPlacaCarreta, 'TEM' as InSituacao
  from GTCLogist
  where coalesce(ltrim(NrPlacaCarreta), '') <> ''
        and ID <> '35514'
        and cast(DtBase as date) = @Hoje;
```

O código #1 não retorna linhas em que a a coluna NrPlacaCarreta esteja sem informação (NULL) ou vazio ou ainda com espaço(s) em branco.

Comment: Desculpa a demora para testar, retomei agora. Perfeito a resposta.